# Why is the JQuery Growfield plugin giving my textarea a default "111 111"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

By default, the textarea should be empty. 
But when I

> alert($("#mytextarea").val())

...the value is:

```
111
111
```

I'm using the Jquery Growfield plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Growfield

And I do this:

```
$("#id_comment_body").growfield({animate:0});
```

Comment: What do you mean, `alert(textarea)`?

Comment: I think this *must* have some specific reason in the context of your page. Is it different  when you don't do the growfield?

Comment: Is it intentional that you are using two differnt DOM element IDs in the question? You talk about `#mytextarea` first but later you refer to `#id_comment_body`.

Comment: I think that @TIMEX was just responding to me badgering about what he meant by the "alert" thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh oh oh oh oh I bet I know what the deal is!!!  Check the docs for that plugin:

> To correctly resize the textarea without flickering or strange behavior to the user, we do the calculations in a dummy invisible text area. The text area is created during focus and removed afterwards. Be careful as the dummy contains the same id and name as the original element so when you do javascript while the user has focus, make sure to not use the element with the class 'growfieldDummy'. If you need to manipulate the growfield text area, do it when the user will not have focus (a user clicks on something to initiate an action to do whatever to the textarea, or during $(document).ready.

I bet that the element you're getting when you do `$('#mytextarea')` is the cloned one!  Try doing what that document says:

```
alert($('#mytextarea:not(.growfieldDummy)').val());
```

Comment: I add that it strikes me as just terrible that that plugin works the way it does.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix that bug, by changing the 'jQuery Growfield Library 2'. 
In function createDummy you have:

```
var dummy = o.clone().addClass('growfieldDummy').attr('name', '').attr('tabindex', -9999)
                               .css({position: 'absolute', left: -9999, top: 0, height: '20px', resize: 'none'})
                               .insertBefore(o).show();
```

change it to:

```
var dummy = o.clone().addClass('growfieldDummy').attr('name', '').attr('id', o.attr('id') + '-dummy')
                               .css({position: 'absolute', left: -9999, top: 0, height: '20px', resize: 'none'})
                               .insertBefore(o).show();
```